# Inner Join in SSIS Excel Source component not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

```
    SELECT   [Sheet1$].ID, [Sheet1$].ReportID, [Sheet1$].CategoryId, [Sheet1$].Male, [Sheet1$].Female,[Sheet1$].Other, [Sheet1$].Remark, [Sheet2$].Name
    FROM  [Sheet1$], [Sheet2$]
    INNER JOIN [Sheet1$] ON [Sheet1$].ID = [Sheet2$].ID
```

I have an Excel workbook with sheet1 and sheet2. I want to do an INNER JOIN between the 2 sheets from an SSIS Excel Source. In the Excel Source Editor, i have selected SQL command for Data Access Mode and typed in the above command.

However when i try to preview the data returned, i'm getting the following error message.

> There was an error displaying the preview.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Cannot repeat table name 'Sheet1$' in FROM clause. (Microsoft Access Database Engine)

Comment: The syntax for a join is generally: `FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON COL1A = COL2B`. Your statement doesn't seem to follow this syntax. Try removing `[Sheet1$],` out of the `FROM` clause.

Comment: maybe leave in from clause just `FROM [Sheet2$]`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, should work "out of the box". The problem is as Turophile said.

```
SELECT   
    [Sheet1$].ID, 
    [Sheet1$].ReportID, 
    [Sheet1$].CategoryId, 
    [Sheet1$].Male, 
    [Sheet1$].Female,
    [Sheet1$].Other, 
    [Sheet1$].Remark, 
    [Sheet2$].Name
FROM  
    [Sheet1$]
    INNER JOIN 
    [Sheet2$] ON [Sheet1$].ID = [Sheet2$].ID
```